# Is it possible to have social buttons with custom images? (with the counters)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I encountered custom share buttons with counter functionality on http://www.woot.com/

This is actually the only place I've seen such a thing with counter functionality (and not just customized images that open the social sites).

Any info on how they did it?
(on that note... is it allowed?)

Thanks

Comment: With counter you mean the amount of likes? If so, you could keep track of these per click or via a cronjob that grabs the likes. **EDIT**: Twitter and Facebook have rules about like buttons, you're actually not allowed to create a custom button for that.

Comment: I feared it was the case but then I saw the woot.com share buttons (with counters) and wanted to do the same...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look at this website: http://dsnacks.me/web/custom-facebook-like-button-design

Answer (score 0):

Try this site [here](http://www.addthis.com/) it will give you the code to add to your site with counters.